# Right align some text within a list item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a nested unordered list which has main content on the left, and I would like to add options which are floated right, such that they are aligned on the right regardless of the level of indentation.

```
<ul>
<li> Item 1 <span class='options'> link </span> </li>
<li> Item 2 <span class='options'> link </span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 3 <span class='options'> link </span> </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have the following css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 400px;
}

.options {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
```

When this is used however the options span is aligned to the right, but 1 line below the expected line.

How can I get the options span to line up with the list item?

TIA,
Adam

Comment: You have a problem with your line widths. #1, #2 and #3 don't have a consistent width among browsers, because of the way your margins and paddings work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of floating, you may want to try absolute positioning.

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.options {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect this helped me a treat. I'm being picky now but and quite update to your solution would be to remove the 'px' from the final 0 for 'right', for best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Using this CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width:400px;
}
.options {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
li li { width:385px}
```

This unfortunately requires your to define a width minus the padding. depending on your flexibility this will work. Tested in Chrome 3.0.

Comment: Hum you solved a marginal issue, not the main issue :). Try your css under IE6.

Answer (score 1):

If modifying the HTML code is OK, you could enclose "Item 1" in a first span and:

- float it to left (still floating .options to the right)
- use `display: inline-block` on both span and `text-align: right` on .options, instead of floats (no compatible with Fx2 though, and only working in IE6/7 because span is an inline elements by default. Would not work with div)