# Right align some text in a CSS ordered list

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a numbered list of strings where I need to add some value at the end of the string floated to the right. I found the following question ([Right align some text within a list item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1188078/2051151)) and this works until the text is just not large enough to force a wrap. The text floated to the right overlaps the text.

Stripped down HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ol class="top3">
    <li>Short name<span class="top3-value">10%</span></li>
    <li>Very very long long long name<span class="top3-value">12%</span></li>
    <li>Very very long long longlonglongname<span class="top3-value">12%</span></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

The container, top3 and top3-value classes are defined as (using LESS syntax):

```
.container {
  width: 175px;
}

ol.top3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #AEAEAE;

  li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    padding: 10px 8px 10px 2em;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;

    span.top3-value {
      padding-left: 1em;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
  }
}
```

See this example: http://codepen.io/kdbruin/pen/xVyEya

The width of the container is set so the problem manifests itself. In my webpage the width can vary and is determined by other elements on the page.

I've tried adding a `display: block` to the top3-value class but this will always force the value below the text, even when there is room enough to put it to the right. Also, this will show the value through the separator lines.

Similar results are shown when using `float: right` instead of absolute positioning of the value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How's this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzGNBB

Comment: @Pete Thanks for the alternative but I've already proposed this as a solution to our client but he rejected it. The arbitrary word breaks was not an adequate solution for him.

Comment: In which case you can't give a fixed width to the container: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdxpNb.  But if your container ever gets to be smaller than your longest word - without word break, you will always get it overlapping, so either your client accepts overlapping words or word break

Comment: @Pete The container has no fixed width set in my website but its width is restricted by the global layout. And the calculated width is about 175 pixels on most screen layouts. I hadn't thought about always being too small and will contact my client that he will probably have to accept some word breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word-break difficulties of my client were a bit exaggerated and this lead me to the following solution based on the various comments and answers.

- Made the list item a flexbox
- Added an additional span for the top3 name with `flex-grow: 1`
- Use `overflow: hidden` to cut off any text that is too long to fit in the box. This was acceptable and provides proper breaks between words

Relevant changes in the CSS:

```
ol.top3 li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ol.top3 li span.top3-name {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ol.top3 li span.top3-value {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

I've created an update pen: http://codepen.io/kdbruin/pen/qZJrYM

Answer (score 0):

If you can able to change the width of the container class, you can put

> width:auto;

So that it will expand till end of the screen.all dynamic values can accommodate here.

Comment: As said in the comments below the question itself, the width is already dynamic but restricted by the surrounding layout. The 175px is about as wide as it will get.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tables and `word-break` to break any really long text might be an option.

I wrapped the list item text in a span for greater control and selectability.

```css
.container {
  width: 175px;
  background: pink;
}
ol.top3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
}
ol.top3 li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 10px 8px 10px 2em;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
  display: table;
}
ol.top3 li:before {
  content: counter(item);
  counter-increment: item;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #444444;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.top3 li span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ol.top3 li span:first-of-type {
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 100%;
}
ol.top3 li span.top3-value {
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol class="top3">
    <li><span>Short name</span><span class="top3-value">10%</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Very very long long long name</span><span class="top3-value">12%</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Very very long long longlonglongnamelonglong</span><span class="top3-value">12%</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```